# Copy a line of text from nano running in a shell over ssh in order to paste into a local gedit instance

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, clipboard, nano

I routinely access remote files using nano in a terminal shell over ssh.

Sometimes I'd like to copy a large amount of text (sometimes one line sometimes a large block) and paste it into a local instance of gedit.

If the amount is small enough to see its easy enough to ctrl-c/ctrl-v or to select the text and right click or shift-ins (I forget which). But if the line is too long I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could always copy over the entire file using scp

```
scp remote-host-ip:~/path/to/file.txt ~/localfile.txt
```

Which works in a similar way to `cp`, copying the file in the first argument to the location provided in the second.